# SSIS Reuse Dynamic Flat File Desitination Filename

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that creates a text flat file from data in a database table.  Everything works perfect except that I need to capture the dynamic filename for use in another process.  I've searched everywhere but haven't found anything close to what I need other than using a ForEach Loop to loop through the directory the file will be stored in.  I can't do that because there's too many things that could go wrong.  I'm currently creating the dynamic filename through variables and it contains a datetime stamp.

Is there a way that I can capture the file name when the file is created in the data flow task so I can use it in another process within the control flow task?

Thank you in advance!

John

Comment: You'll have to do it through `Script task`.

Comment: Thank you @PrabhatG I guess I need to learn how to write the script.  Any thoughts on where to look on how to write the code?  I can write some VBA and SQL but I've never had to write anything in SSIS.

Comment: SSIS scripts are written in your choice of VB.NET or C#.NET.   So you'd look into tutorials for those languages.